# Middleman helpers not working in markdown file

Tags: middleman

I'm using `middleman` and `redcarpet` for **markdown rendering**

In my markdown `file`, I used `helpers`.

If I save that file with `.md` extension, `helpers` did not work.

If I save that file with `.md.erb` extension, it works fine.

But I want to save file with `.md` extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution,

Refer this [issue]: https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/602

Redcarpet renders the file in the order of its extension.If the file has .html.md.erb, it renders the file in order from right to left.(i.e: erb => md => html)

Comment: A bit of a correction - it's Middleman that renders each bit right to left.